# Angular 1.5 variable not working untill it has been called once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this list of items as below, that the user has two filtering options on. One is a select menu which works perfect but the other is a button, which wne clicked it will only show the objects that have a certain field.

The problem Im having with this is that upon first loading the page the variable that the button changes is not showing untill I click the button, now this is only for debugging but either way it does not change the filtering in the list

```
<div flex="10">
    <md-button  type="submit" ng-click="showOnlyOffline = !showOnlyOffline">
        {{showOnlyOffline == false ? 'Show All' : 'Only Show Offline'}}
    </md-button>
</div>

{{showOnlyOffline }}

<div ng-repeat="data in dataArray |filter :{timezone: selectedTimeZone} | filter :{status: showOnlyOffline } " flex="45">
    {{data.name}}
    {{data.status}}
</div>
```

where `data.status` is a boolean and `data.timezone` is a string timezone

and in my controller I have it set so that

```
$scope.showOnlyOffline = false;
```

It's not a huge problem but it feels like something is broken when you first click it since the user would not get any feedback without the true or false which shouldn't be there once im done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change reference as below and try.

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.showOnlyOffline = false;
```

and  in html change the references to model.showOnlyOffline

Comment: The reason is scope of md-button.its creating a new variable called as showOnlyOffline inside me-button scope. so by making model.variable you are asking it to use scope that of controller.

Answer (score 1):

As @ravichandra reddy suggested, bind the primitive value to an object.

The reason behind this is that "md-button" create new scope, that is not isolated at all, but doesn't have access to primitive value. This article explain it very well
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Ohhhh i see. Thank you for explaining that

Answer (score 0):

try this, here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3294/) created for your problem

```
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                <div flex="10">
                    <md-button type="submit" ng-click="showOnlyOffline = !showOnlyOffline">
                        {{showOnlyOffline && 'Only Show Offline' || 'Show All'}}
                    </md-button>
                </div>
                {{showOnlyOffline }}
                <div ng-repeat="data in dataArray | filter :{status: showOnlyOffline } " flex="45">
                    {{data.name}} {{data.status}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

controller

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.showOnlyOffline = false;
        $scope.selectedTimeZone = new Date();
        $scope.dataArray = [{ name: "asd", status: true, timezone: $scope.selectedTimeZone }, { name: "qwerty", status: false, timezone: $scope.selectedTimeZone }];
    }
```